# Executing jar file to load file in classpath

Tags: java, unix, apache-poi, java-io

My MainClass.java has a main method which contains following code to read an excel file

```
String xlsxFilename = args[0];
try (InputStream fis = MainClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(xlsxFilename);
    Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);) {
    ...
```

This class is contained in a jar file and is placed in folder named lib and I'm executing it using using a shell script

run.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
CP=lib/*:
java -cp "$CP" in.test.MainClass $1
```

Now I run the command to execute the sh file

```
sh run.sh Sample.xlsx
```

But this throwing an exception,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:79)
```

I guess the exception is because the getResourceAsStream is not loading the excel file, and the fis object is null. Is the current directory not visible to getResourceAsStream()? How can I read the xls file inside the current directory in my MainClass.java ?

Comment: i think if you want to read as a resource, the excel file should be placed within the jar file somewhere with a qualified package.

Comment: Is the Excel file in the same directory that you are running the program from? Or in a Jar? Or elsewhere?

Comment: Excel file is in the same directory in which the script is being run.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in this line of code:

```
InputStream fis = MainClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(xlsxFilename)
```

The file `xlsxFilename` will be find by the classloader if and only if your XLS is in the classpath, i.e. in a folder specified by the `-classpath` option to the JVM, or inside your *jar* archive. In the first case your line command should became something like this:

```
java -classpath "your.jar:/path/to/xls/folder" in.test.MainClass $1
```

Clearly `/path/to/xls/folder` is the folder where you have to put your xls file.

In the latter case, the XLS file has to be in the root folder of you `.class` files.

I suggest you to load the XLS file using an absolute file path.

Comment: Is the path from which the sh file is executed part of class path. I am able to run the same in a windows environment using a batch file. `@ECHO OFF`
`set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;lib/*;`
`java in.test.MainClass %1`